# Having a table, add colors

Tags: tables

If I have

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
 text& text &text  &text  \\ 
\hline
text& text &text  &text   \\ 
\hline
text& text &text  &text   \\ 
\hline
text& text &text  &text   \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to modify this code and adding color to the rows? Also, can I change the color of the lines?

---

I have a new code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\definecolor{newgreen}{RGB}{0,128,64}
\definecolor{lightgreen}{RGB}{0,166,83}

\begin{document}

\arrayrulecolor{white}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|} 
\hline
\rowcolor{newgreen} text& text &text  &text  \\ 
\hline
\rowcolor{lightgreen}text& text &text  &text   \\ 
\hline
\rowcolor{lightgreen}text& text &text  &text   \\ 
\hline
\rowcolor{lightgreen}text& text &text  &text   \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I used \arrayrulecolor{white} but it doesn't give me all white lines for the entire table.

Comment: I get white horizontal and vertical lines when running your "new" code. Which pdf viewer do you use?

Comment: Adobe Reader XI.

Comment: You shouldn't. Adobe Reader locks your .pdf, and you have to close it before recompiling. Moreover, it doesn't support inverse and forward search, as far as I know.. The best choice under Windows is SumatraPDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`xcolor`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) package and its `table` option. Refer to the package documentation for further details. The colors in my example are not the most appropriate, but they are so just for illustration purposes:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\rowcolor{green!20} text& text &text  &text  \\ 
\hline
\rowcolor{magenta!20}text& text &text  &text   \\ 
\hline
\rowcolor{blue!20}text& text &text  &text   \\ 
\hline
\rowcolor{yellow!20}text& text &text  &text   \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}\par\bigskip


{
\rowcolors{1}{gray!25}{yellow!10}
\arrayrulecolor{red!75!black}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
 text& text &text  &text  \\ 
\hline
text& text &text  &text   \\ 
\hline
text& text &text  &text   \\ 
\hline
text& text &text  &text   \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

### Update

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\definecolor{newgreen}{RGB}{0,128,64}
\definecolor{lightgreen}{RGB}{0,166,83}

\begin{document}

\arrayrulecolor{white}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|} 
\hline
\rowcolor{newgreen} text& text &text  &text  \\ 
\hline
\rowcolor{lightgreen}text& text &text  &text   \\ 
\hline
\rowcolor{lightgreen}text& text &text  &text   \\ 
\hline
\rowcolor{lightgreen}text& text &text  &text   \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I've edited my post with a particular example but I couldn't get it to work watching your code.

Comment: @Oshnaj of course it works; see my updated answer and the image with all rules in white. What do you mean by "I couldn't get it to work"? Perhaps is just a viewer problem? To see if this is the case, try zooming the resulting document.

Comment: Yes! I just zoomed and I realized it was a viewer problem. Thanks for the help!